# How to pass a component type to render to another component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base component (**MyBaseComponent**) receiving data from it's invoker (**App**).

I want to know if it's possible for my base component to be told by it's invoker what 'display' component it should use --  **MyDisplayComponent** or **MyOtherDisplayComponent**.

I.e., I want to do something along the lines of:

```
<my-base [data]="names">
    <my-other-display></my-other-display>
</my-base>
```

and in a different location, something like:

```
<my-base [data]="names">
    <my-display></my-display>
</my-base>
```

But I'm unable to figure out how to do this.  I've tried different use of `<ng-content>`, but I don't think it provides for this level of flexibility.  Additionally `ComponentFactoryResolver` sounds like it could work, but again I'm not sure how it could work in an iterative fashion, as well as pass data to the child controls.

[Here's a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jzvx63LodDUiJfg2kBhv?p=preview), with the code outlined below, which hopefully conveys what I'm attempting.

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {MyBaseComponent} from './my-base.component'
import {MyDisplayComponent} from './my-display.component'
import {MyOtherDisplayComponent} from './my-other-display.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-base [data]="names">

      <!-- Is it possible to specify the 'display component' type to use here? -->

      </my-base>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  names: string[] = ["bill", "bob", "ben"];

  constructor() {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyBaseComponent, MyDisplayComponent, MyOtherDisplayComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**my-base.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-base',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let datum of data">

    <!-- Instead of specifying the display components here,
    how can I specify the components type to use for display
    at the 'app.ts' level? -->

    <!--<my-display [value]="datum"></my-display>-->
    <my-other-display [value]="datum"></my-other-display>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class MyBaseComponent {

  @Input()
  data: string[];

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**my-display.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-display',
  template: `
  <div>{{value}}</div>
  `,
})
export class MyDisplayComponent {
  @Input()
  value:string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**my-other-display.component.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-other-display',
  template: `
  <div>{{value}}! {{value}}! {{value}}!</div>
  `,
})
export class MyOtherDisplayComponent {

  @Input()
  value:string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Again, the big 'ask' here is whether it's possible to specify the `display` components for use at the **app.ts** (invoker) level so that the **my-base.component.ts** file can be ignorant of the specific implementation used in a given situation.

It may be that the **my-base.component.ts** file needs to pass a class name or a type to use that adheres to some kind of interface...?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can try using `ngTemplateOutlet` directive like

**my-base.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-base',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let datum of data">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmpl; context: { $implicit: datum }"></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyBaseComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Input() data: string[];
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-base [data]="names">
      <ng-template let-item>
        <my-other-display [value]="item"></my-other-display>
      </ng-template>
    </my-base>

    <my-base [data]="names">
      <ng-template let-item>
        <my-display [value]="item"></my-display>
      </ng-template>
    </my-base>
  `,
})
export class App {
  names: string[] = ["bill", "bob", "ben"];
}
```

**[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hb2Ofb7x42RqDqvtQiLs?p=preview)**

2) Using `ngForTemplate`. Almost the same approach with only one difference in

**my-base.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-base',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let datum of data; template: tmpl"></div>`
})
export class MyBaseComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Input() data: string[];
}
```

**[Forked Plunker ngForTemplate](http://plnkr.co/edit/ETDdqiC19chqhSitCvHq?p=preview)**

Comment: This is excellent- exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to use `ngComponentOutlet` to choose the component and probably `ngIf` or switch for which to show,  I'm not sure what your going for.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ta5f3NYdyYUMXKhrc1ax?p=preview)

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="MyDisplayComponent"></ng-container>

 // in module
entryComponents : [ MyDisplayComponent, MyOtherDisplayComponent],
```

Comment: I see your update.  So in this scenario, how would the 'display' components have the 'names' passed to them as inputs?  In the given plunker, nothing renders

Answer (score 1):

instead of ng-content  you can simply solve using if and else.

base component will pass true or false value to render

**app.ts**

```
 <my-base [data]="names" [isValid]=false>
```

**MyBaseComponent.ts**

```
 <div *ngIf="isValid;then content else other_content"></div>

<ng-template #content> <div *ngFor="let datum of data"> 
    <my-display [value]="datum"></my-display>
  </div></ng-template>
<ng-template #other_content> <div *ngFor="let datum of data">

    <my-other-display [value]="datum"></my-other-display>
  </div></ng-template>
```

Comment: The point is I don't want to hardcode any of the components into MyBaseComponent.  I want to have them specified at the **app.ts** level.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you can use NgSwitch

```
<div [ngSwitch]="typeOfComponent">
  <my-display  [value]="datum" *ngSwitchCase="type1"></my-other-display>
  <my-other-display  [value]="datum" *ngSwitchCase="type2"></my-other-display>
  <my-other-display  [value]="datum" *ngSwitchCase="type3"></my-other-display>      
</div>
```

Comment: The question is whether it's possible to have the **app.ts** "invoker" code specify what component to use for display as some kind of variable.  This isn't any help to that end.

Comment: You can initiate a service with some properties in the app.ts and inject that service in the base component and show what you want based on those properties.